# Unexpected implicit conversion

Tags: scala, implicit

In the following example:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

class Fraction(val num: Int, val den: Int) {
  def *(other: Fraction) = new Fraction(num * other.num, den * other.den)
}

implicit def int2Fraction(n: Int) = new Fraction(n, 1)
implicit def fraction2Double(f: Fraction) = f.num * 1.0 / f.den
```

why is the result a `Double` and not a `Fraction`? In other words - why is the `fraction2Double` method applied here and not `int2Fraction`?

```
scala> 4 * new Fraction(1, 2)
res0: Double = 2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the second implicit method (`fraction2Double`) is prioritized by the compiler because it does not require modification of the object to which the `*` method is applied.

If we were to remove the `fraction2Double` method and only leave `int2Fraction`, the result would be different:

```
scala> 4 * new Fraction(1, 2)
res0: Fraction = 4/2
```

Source: ["Scala for the Impatient" by Cay S. Horstmann](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134540565)